# React Native expo build failed due to unknown errors

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to create a react native build for Android APK using expo. I have already logged in to EAS expo user and after some time, I get unknown errors (screenshot attached below)

Below is my package.json file content:

[image]

I have fired this command on terminal :

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

[image]

Can somebody please help me to debug these issues?

Comment: Have you checked if you have installed async-storage within your node_modules?

Comment: @StefanoOrtisi Would you please check the package.json file image added? I have edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: try upgrading react-native to a newer version

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual information, post them as code-formatted text. Also, please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

1. try running the command `expo doctor`, it will check if your
   dependencies are compatible with your expo version.
2. Run `expo doctor --fix-dependencies` to fix incompatible packages.
3. try running your project locally and check if you are facing any other issues before building it using eas.
4. If none of this help try upgrading to the latest expo version by following the upgrade guide

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).